# Why APK contains v4 support resources?

Tags: android

My app minimum sdk version is 16. and I have not added v4-support in my gradle. But when I analyze apk then large size of resources is the v4 support drawables. I want know why they are included in APK while my app is being developed for minimum 16 version.

**There are converted png vector-images in v4 packages.** But my app does not need v4 support.

[image: sc]

```
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 28
    ...
}
```

**I need a solution that remove v4 support resources from APK, so my app size reduce much.**

My dependencies are -

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-alpha2'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.16'
    implementation 'com.github.tbruyelle:rxpermissions:0.10.2'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.3.+'
    implementation 'com.github.medyo:android-about-page:1.2.2'

    implementation 'com.ogaclejapan.smarttablayout:library:1.6.1@aar'
    implementation 'com.ogaclejapan.smarttablayout:utils-v4:1.6.1@aar'

    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.2'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.picasso:picasso2-okhttp3-downloader:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    implementation 'net.yslibrary.keyboardvisibilityevent:keyboardvisibilityevent:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.ronaldsmartin:Material-ViewPagerIndicator:1.+'
    implementation('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.23.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    }
    implementation "com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:$SDP_VERSION"
    implementation "com.intuit.ssp:ssp-android:$SDP_VERSION"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:${RETROFIT_VER}"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:${RETROFIT_VER}"
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.10.0'
    implementation 'com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:8.0.1'
    implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.1.1'
    implementation ('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.5@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    implementation 'com.tbuonomo.andrui:viewpagerdotsindicator:2.1.2'
}
```

Comment: "v4" is not the same as "SDK 4". The weird version numbering has been fixed with the introduction of androidx.

Comment: @ZUNJAE I am in problem because I put svg in app to reduce app size but svg icons are converted to multiple png with building apk.

Answer (score 2):

The support libraries version number indicates **the minimum API level** they originally supported. Yet with time older Android API levels are being removed from the libraries when already obsolete, but the version number has been kept as it was. So, you shouldn't look at the support libraries version number as a co-related identifier with your development API target.

And by seeing your Gradle, it seems the v4 support library may be included as a dependency from one of the third-party libraries you are using.

**UPDATE FOR THE COMMENTS**:

You could try to set **minifyEnabled true** in your gradle, but I doubt it will have any impact, as these resources are used by your third-party dependencies.

For what you are asking there is no magic bullet and not possible straight solution in a kind of a setting that will remove them.

What you need to do, is to investigate which of your third-party dependencies are using the support libraries, and evaluate if you can find an alternative. Just to give you an example, I did some of the work for you, but you will need to check all of your dependencies:

**com.ogaclejapan.smarttablayout:library** uses:

- com.android.support:support-v4
- com.android.support:support-v13

**com.github.medyo:android-about-page** uses:

- com.android.support:appcompat-v7

**com.github.bumptech.glide:glide** uses:

- com.android.support:support-fragment
- com.android.support:support-v4
- com.android.support:appcompat-v7

**org.greenrobot:eventbus** uses:

- com.android.support:support-v4

Comment: I want a solution bro, because v4 drawables are taking much space, which contains converted vector to png.

Comment: Does v4 mean support for 4th version of SDK?

Comment: No.  The support libraries are to give backward compatibility to several API levels and not only one.  What the v4 originally meant was that the library could be used from SDK >=4 (so from SDK 4 and any API level above it). But as Android has already deprecated older versions, now at the time of this answer v4 means the library can be used from SDK version >=14.

Comment: I tell you my purpose, I used svg image to reduce app size, but svg icons are being converted to png in apk. And it is taking more size than using single png icon. I want my apk contain only 1 svg image. No other pngs for that svg.

Comment: The next link will help you to solve the SVG/PNG issue, but this will be only for your own SVG resources and not the ones used in your dependecies: https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/appcompat-v23-2-age-of-the-vectors-91cbafa87c88